# Go tutorial: Channels and Buffered Channels

Tags: go, buffer, channel

Why does not the channel *c* buffered out when the second value is sent via another go routine and the first value sent isn't received?

```
package main
import "fmt"

func sum(s []int, c chan int) {
    sum := 0
    for _, v := range s {
        sum += v
    }
    c <- sum // send sum to c   
}

func main() {
    s := []int{7, 2, 8, -9, 4, 0}
    c := make(chan int)
    go sum(s[:len(s)/2], c)
    go sum(s[len(s)/2:], c)
    x, y :=  <-c ,<-c// receive from c
    fmt.Println(x,y ,x+y)
}
```

What I was expecting is an error-

> fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

This occurs when there is a block when the buffer is full. Since channel c has size 1, sending the second value should have given the above error.

What is happening in above code ?

Comment: Because the channel c is unbuffered. Unbuffered channels don't buffer messages by definition.

Comment: What does this `channel c buffered out` mean. What you are expecting in your code.

Comment: I was expecting an error- `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`
This occurs when there is a block when the buffer is full. Since channel `c` has size 1, sending the second value should have given the above error.

Comment: It will not report error until there is someone to receive the value on other side which is your case

Comment: Check this code https://play.golang.org/p/dTekL0kIOHW it will not show error But this will https://play.golang.org/p/cSerXev2vBb. Since second code will wait for value to be send from the channel.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because a write can’t succeed immediately, you won’t get the “deadlock” error so long as there’s some other goroutine that can run.

Let’s imagine a scheduling model where a `go` function immediately starts the goroutine and makes as much forward progress as it can before yielding to someone else.  Then this will happen:

1. The program will call `sum()` for the first half of the list, calculate the sum, and try to write it to the channel, but since there is no listener, it will block.
2. The program will call `sum()` for the second half of the list, calculate the sum, and try to write it to the channel, but since there is no listener, it will block.
3. `main()` will try to read from the channel, wakes up one of the previous goroutines, and gets the value from it.
4. `main()` will try to read from the channel, wakes up the other blocked goroutine, and gets the value from it.
5. Nobody’s blocked on channel input or output any more and all of the goroutines (including `main()`) can run to completion.

You can do the same exercise if you pretend `go` just schedules something in the background and continues running the main goroutine.  The important thing is that as soon as there’s a paired read and write on the same channel, both will proceed.